# Isotope Internet Explorer scroll issue when selected using function click

Tags: javascript, function, click, jquery-isotope

Firstly, apologies for including the below 'dev' URL, but this shows the functionality much better than me wripping it out into a jsfiddle.

I use isotope on the below page:

http://orchards.t3.ext.starberry.com/property-sales/properties-for-sale-in-london

**The functionality**

1. When you scroll down the page to the bottom & click one of the properties, it auto scrolls back to the top to show the selected property details.
2. When you close the selected property, by clicking the 'X', it scrolls back down to the position that you previously selected/clicked.

**The Issue**

This works great in Chrome & Safari, but I have to make this work in IE9 & IE10 which it doesn't.

Can anyone advise or see what is wrong with the below JavaScript, stopping this from works in IE9 & 10?

```
var oldScroll = 0;
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    $(function(){
      var $container = jQuery('#startekContainer');
      $items = jQuery('.quick-view');
      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: 50
          //layoutMode: 'fitColumns'
        },

        getSortData : {
          selected : function( $item ){
            // sort by selected first, then by original order
            return ($item.hasClass('selected') ? -1000 : 0 ) + $item.index();
          }
        },
        sortBy : 'selected'
      });

      jQuery('.close-image').click(function(event){
        var $this = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
        $this.prev().trigger('click', event, this);
      });
      $items.click(function(event, origEvent){
        //event.preventDefault();
        var $this = jQuery(this).parent();
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') && !origEvent ) {
            // only allow the close button to close
            return true;
        }
        curScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
        $('body').scrollTop( 0 );
        // don't proceed if already selected
        var $previousSelected = jQuery('.selected');
        if ( !$this.hasClass('selected') ) {
            $this.addClass('selected');
            $this.find('.results-image').addClass('hidden');
            $this.find('.swiper').removeClass('hidden');
            var thisSwiper = $this.find('.swiper .ImageSlider').data('swiper');
            thisSwiper.reInit();
            thisSwiper.swipeTo(0);
            thisSwiper.startAutoplay();
        }
        else {
            $('body').scrollTop(oldScroll);
        }
        $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');
        $previousSelected.find('.results-image').removeClass('hidden');
        $previousSelected.find('.swiper').addClass('hidden');
        oldScroll = curScroll;

        // update sortData for new items size
        $container
          .isotope( 'updateSortData', $this )
          .isotope( 'updateSortData', $previousSelected )
          .isotope();
      });
        });
    });
```

**Answering my own question here:**

$(document)

instead of either $('body') or $('html,body')